# App Engine Datastore is just storing a maximum of 150 elements

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My App Engine datastore is just storing a maximum of 150 elements. Is there some of limit for the free version of the datastore?

Here is my Java Servlet which is storing data in my datastore. I used Low Level API for datastore to implement this.

```
public static long id = 0;

public void doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    id++;

    String eventid = null;
    long timestamp = 0;
    eventid = request.getParameter("eventid");
    timestamp = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("timestamp"));

    response.setContentType("text/plain");  
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
    response.getWriter().write("Request received " + eventid);

    Entity eventEntity = new Entity("EventTYPE", id);
    eventEntity.setProperty("eventid", eventid);
    eventEntity.setProperty("timestamp", timestamp);

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(eventEntity);

}
```

Is something wrong with my code? Or is there some limit with the free version of App Engine Datastore?

Comment: There are limits on free apps, but not (directly) on the number of entities. How are you arriving at the conclusion that only 150 are being stored? What happens when you try to add another? Do you get an error?

Comment: Found my problem. The problem is setting id=0 in the Java file. Whenever I restart my server. My id is reset to 0 which is overriding the previous values with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, everytime the Java code is ran, you reinitialize the variable to 0.

You can solve this by having the id variable fetched from the datastore instead of just being a Java variable. This way it will stay the updated version even after you restart the instance or boot up another one.